# Google maps ios api using user's location in fitbounds

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to set a bounds between the users location and a selected marker.  I can set everything up properly but when I try to use the users location (mapView_.myLocation.coordinate) it says the lat and long are both 0.  I did create a button to center the camera on the users location and it gets the lat and long just fine.  Does not make any sense to me.  Also I don't have a device set up to test so I am using xcodes iOS simulator with a location put into the simulator (is that where my problem is?).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access `myLocation.coordinate` from `loadView` or similar, ie when the app first starts up?

Generally when enabling location services the app doesn't receive a location update immediately, it comes through after some delay. So it's possible that `myLocation.coordinate` won't be valid in `loadView`, but will have a value set some time later (which is why it works with your button).

You could perhaps listen for changes to `myLocation`, and then set your bounds when it changes to something.